# Kendo UI GRID with web api paging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I am using kendo Grid on my client and the backend service is on web api. Server paging didn't work, so I followed [these instructions](http://www.telerik.com/forums/serverpaging-request-always-null)
but I get an error like this

> TypeError: kendo.data.transports.webapi is not a constructor

I am not using MVC wrappers on my client
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what was missing.
I didn't include kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js